# How to implement Synchronous web service on JMS / MOM system?

Tags: java, web-services, jms, esb, eai

I am working on a project which have many legacy heterogeneous systems. We are planing to connect them using  JMS/MOM/ESB but need Synchronous web service calls from client. 
i.e Request/Response architecture using web service is a requirement.
Client will make calls and wait for response.

**My question is  how can we implement Request/ response system which internally work on JMS/MOM to connect desperate systems?**

**Second question :** Do any existing JMS/MOM or ESB implementations support such synchronous architecture?

Answer (score 0):

first about second question: All of them support such architecture.

second about first:-)
just a brief idea:
when you send a message to target JMS Queue you have to have a unique message ID (in headers as example) then target system must answer (response) to "replyTo" queue. Then you have to have listener on that replyTo queue with filter by that unique ID and your flow must wait for response from that listener.

Something like that...